# Will questions on the workings of NexusMods be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I like to know more about the ways in which [NexusMods](https://www.nexusmods.com/) has treated their modders. I remember in 2021 they announced they would no longer support modders deleting their own creations, which caused some controversy. On the other hand, they have paid over $3 million to modders.

**Would such a question be on-topic here on Arqade?**

A few additional thoughts:

- I think having more questions focusing on auxiliary services like this one will enrich our community.
- It might become a self-answered question, as I like to do some digging.
- Modding is very much a part of gaming. For modding itself we have [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but this website acts as a hub between modding gamers and modders. The existence of and actions taken by a website like NexusMods have great implications for gamers like us, which seems to make it very much on-topic, so I am mostly doubting the [germaneness](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13379/germaneness-of-question-on-game-ban) of the nature of the question.
- With the titular "here" I mean on the main site :)
- Coming back to this question later, I *think* my original intended question was, and what will be a good example question is: ***what was the impact on the modding community of the decision by NexusMods to stop supporting modders to delete their mods?***

Comment: Can you provide at least the title of the question you would like to ask?  With the information this post presents currently, I am somewhat leaning towards off-topic, since I don't think we can really speak to how a particular website treats their users.

Comment: @TimmyJim Very good point! That was the intent behind the question, which indeed seems to make it off-topic. I guess I started thinking about such a question because I wanted to know the power such a website has over, or the implications it can have for modding gamers. But that would be way too broad a question. I'll ponder on the exact question :)

Comment: How does [this web site] work, is not a valid question on any SE, except asking about *SE* on SE. NM is not an "auxiliary service" like say Steam. It's a website that hosts files that you can DL for free. How would anything about how they treat their up-loaders be anything other than tangential to the game that the mod is for? You just want to rant about the BS going on over there and for some reason want to bring that toxicity here?

Comment: "this website acts as a hub between modding gamers and modders" no it doesn't. For Minecraft, thank god, it's specifically off-topic. And I've never even seen a question about *any* of the 700 mods I have between F4 and Skyrim.

Comment: Will questions on the [inner] workings of NexusMods[*.com*] be on-topic here? No. Try Skeptics.SE

Comment: @Mazura: You're prematurely accusing the questioner of wanting to rant, but your comments come off as ranting far more than anything in this question or the proposed main site question. (Also, the Skeptics site is absolutely not an appropriate site for asking arbitrary questions about how websites treat their users. It's for fact-checking notable claims.)

Comment: @Mazura Did you actually read the question and its comments, properly? That description was about NexusMods, I admitted I haven't found a proper question to begin with, and it certainly wasn't "*how does [this site] work?*", I never claimed it is an auxiliary service "*like Steam*", but it definitely is an auxiliary service to modding gamers. "*And I've never even seen a question about any of the 700 mods I have between F4 and Skyrim*"—despite that not at all being what this is about, have you ever visited our main site? :D

Comment: I think that this type of question might be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/. Or maybe https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ like how Mazura said. Depending on the exact question you want to ask. But whichever you think is more appropriate, be sure to read the help section and which questions are indeed on-topic there.

Comment: Note also that you don't have to ask on Stack Exchange in particular. You can ask the folks on [/r/skyrimmods](https://old.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/) for their opinions, and they're probably much more willing to have this sort of freewheeling (opinion-based) conversation than we are.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that NexusMods could be considered a 'gaming-specific utility' in that it is primarily used by gamers to mod games. Thus, questions about using Nexus in the context of modding games *from the end-user perspective* should be on-topic. For example, asking about various features of the site or the Mod Manager/other tools they offer.

**However**, the example question you give is asking about control over modding assets and how that affect(s|ed) the modding community. The thing is, it mostly affects mod creators and is (mostly) irrelevant to the end users using mods.

Thus in my opinion, as a site that mostly caters to end users, Arqade would probably not be an appropriate fit for that question. It *might* be more relevant on Game Development SE? (although check with them first!) as writing mods is closer to on-topic over there thus the audience may be a better fit, or alternatively - WebApps or Skeptics as others have mentioned.